# mvc prevent action link from loop

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

Any idea on how to stop this action link from loop over and over

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{

<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Subjects.SubjectName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ScoreName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.JanHomework)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.JanQuiz)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.JanExam)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Result)
    </td>

     @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditScore", new { id = item.SubjectID })
</tr>
}
```

I have tried to remove the action link from the For-each loop bracket but it will show error, My plan is i want this view to be redirected to another view with the  same controller and model.

**Current View**

```
public ActionResult Index_Test(int id)
{
   List<Term1Score> score = db.Term1Scores.Where(x => x.SubjectID == id).ToList();
   return View(score);
}
```

Redirect to this view

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult EditScore(int id)
{
   List<Term1Score> score = db.Term1Scores.Where(x => x.SubjectID == id).ToList();
   return View(score);
}
```

Comment: *but it will show error* what error exactly?